# Error Compile unresolved external

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

When I tried to compile source, I got this error, I try fix it, but I don't know how to. Here's the error

```
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlParseFile
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlDocGetRootElement
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlStrcmp
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlFreeDoc
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlGetProp
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__xmlFree
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushstring
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettable
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnumber
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pcallk
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaL_newstate
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaopen_base
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaopen_math
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaopen_string
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaopen_io
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushcclosure
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_setglobal
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getglobal
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_createtable
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_tonumberx
1>actions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_tolstring
1>ioaccountxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlNewMutex
1>ioaccountxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlMutexLock
1>ioaccountxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlMutexUnlock
1>iomapxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlLineNumbersDefault
1>ioplayerxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlNewNode
1>ioplayerxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlAddChild
1>ioplayerxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlNewDoc
1>ioplayerxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlNewDocNode
1>ioplayerxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlSetProp
1>ioplayerxml.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlSaveFile
1>luascript.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_close
1>luascript.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_isstring
1>luascript.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawlen
1>luascript.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop
1>luascript.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_isnumber
1>luascript.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settable
1>networkmessage.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _recv@16
1>networkmessage.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WSAGetLastError@0
1>networkmessage.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ioctlsocket@12
1>networkmessage.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _send@16
1>npc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getstack
1>npc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnil
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _getpeername@12
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _closesocket@4
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WSAStartup@8
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WSACleanup@0
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _inet_addr@4
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gethostname@8
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gethostbyname@4
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _htons@4
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _htonl@4
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _socket@12
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _bind@12
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _listen@8
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _select@20
1>otserv.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _accept@12
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_pushcclosure(struct lua_State *,int (__cdecl*)(struct lua_State *),int)" (?lua_pushcclosure@@YAXPAUlua_State@@P6AH0@ZH@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_setglobal(struct lua_State *,char const *)" (?lua_setglobal@@YAXPAUlua_State@@PBD@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl lua_pushstring(struct lua_State *,char const *)" (?lua_pushstring@@YAPBDPAUlua_State@@PBD@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_gettable(struct lua_State *,int)" (?lua_gettable@@YAXPAUlua_State@@H@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_pushnumber(struct lua_State *,double)" (?lua_pushnumber@@YAXPAUlua_State@@N@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_createtable(struct lua_State *,int,int)" (?lua_createtable@@YAXPAUlua_State@@HH@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl lua_pcallk(struct lua_State *,int,int,int,int,int (__cdecl*)(struct lua_State *))" (?lua_pcallk@@YAHPAUlua_State@@HHHHP6AH0@Z@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl lua_toboolean(struct lua_State *,int)" (?lua_toboolean@@YAHPAUlua_State@@H@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_settop(struct lua_State *,int)" (?lua_settop@@YAXPAUlua_State@@H@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_getglobal(struct lua_State *,char const *)" (?lua_getglobal@@YAXPAUlua_State@@PBD@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl lua_tonumberx(struct lua_State *,int,int *)" (?lua_tonumberx@@YANPAUlua_State@@HPAH@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_pushnil(struct lua_State *)" (?lua_pushnil@@YAXPAUlua_State@@@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl lua_next(struct lua_State *,int)" (?lua_next@@YAHPAUlua_State@@H@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_pushboolean(struct lua_State *,int)" (?lua_pushboolean@@YAXPAUlua_State@@H@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl lua_tolstring(struct lua_State *,int,unsigned int *)" (?lua_tolstring@@YAPBDPAUlua_State@@HPAI@Z)
1>spells.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lua_settable(struct lua_State *,int)" (?lua_settable@@YAXPAUlua_State@@H@Z)
1>status.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlNewTextChild
1>status.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmlDocDumpMemory
1>C:\Users\Raven\Desktop\Darkness\Darkness\Release\Darkness.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 75 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

#ifndef __IOACCOUNTXML_H
#define __IOACCOUNTXML_H

#include <string>

#include "libxml/xmlmemory.h"
#include "libxml/parser.h"

#include "definitions.h"
#include "ioaccount.h"

/** Player-Loaders implemented with XML */
class IOAccountXML : protected IOAccount {
  public:
    /** Get a textual description of what source is used
      * \returns Name of the source*/
    virtual char* getSourceDescription(){return "XML";};
    virtual Account loadAccount(unsigned long accno);

#ifdef YUR_BUILTIN_AAC
    virtual bool saveAccount(const Account& account);
#endif //YUR_BUILTIN_AAC

    virtual bool getPassword(unsigned long accno, const std::string &name, std::string &password);
    IOAccountXML();
    virtual ~IOAccountXML(){};
};

#endif
```

ioaccountxml.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ioaccountxml.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
#include "luascript.h"
#include "tools.h"

extern xmlMutexPtr xmlmutex;
extern LuaScript g_config; 

IOAccountXML::IOAccountXML(){
    if(xmlmutex == NULL){
        xmlmutex = xmlNewMutex();
    }
}

Account IOAccountXML::loadAccount(unsigned long accno){
    Account acc;

    std::stringstream accsstr;
    std::string datadir = g_config.getGlobalString("datadir");
    accsstr << datadir + "accounts/" << accno << ".xml";
    std::string filename = accsstr.str();
    std::transform(filename.begin(), filename.end(), filename.begin(), tolower);
    xmlMutexLock(xmlmutex);
    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseFile(filename.c_str());
    if (doc)
    {
        xmlNodePtr root, p, tmp;
        root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

        if (xmlStrcmp(root->name,(const xmlChar*) "account"))
        {
            xmlFreeDoc(doc);            
            xmlMutexUnlock(xmlmutex);
            return acc;
        }

        p = root->children;

        // perhaps verify name
        char* nodeValue = NULL;
        nodeValue = (char*)xmlGetProp(root, (const xmlChar *)"pass");
        acc.password  = nodeValue;
        xmlFreeOTSERV(nodeValue);

        nodeValue = (char*)xmlGetProp(root, (xmlChar*)"type");
        acc.accType  = atoi(nodeValue);
        xmlFreeOTSERV(nodeValue);

        nodeValue = (char*)xmlGetProp(root, (xmlChar*)"premDays");
        acc.premDays  = atoi(nodeValue);
        xmlFreeOTSERV(nodeValue);

        // now load in characters.
        while (p)
        {
            const char* str = (char*)p->name;

            if (strcmp(str, "characters") == 0)
            {
                tmp = p->children;
                while(tmp)
                {
                    nodeValue = (char*)xmlGetProp(tmp, (xmlChar*)"name");

                    if(nodeValue) {
                        if(strcmp((const char*)tmp->name, "character") == 0) {
                            acc.charList.push_back(std::string(nodeValue));
                        }

                        xmlFreeOTSERV(nodeValue);
                    }

                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
            }
            p = p->next;
        }

        xmlFreeDoc(doc);

        // Organize the char list.
        acc.charList.sort();
        acc.accnumber = accno;
    }   
    xmlMutexUnlock(xmlmutex);
    return acc;
}


bool IOAccountXML::getPassword(unsigned long accno, const std::string &name, std::string &password)
{
    std::string acc_password;

    std::stringstream accsstr;
    std::string datadir = g_config.getGlobalString("datadir");
    accsstr << datadir + "accounts/" << accno << ".xml";;
    std::string filename = accsstr.str();
    std::transform(filename.begin(), filename.end(), filename.begin(), tolower);

    xmlMutexLock(xmlmutex);
    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseFile(filename.c_str());
    if (doc)
    {
        xmlNodePtr root, p, tmp;
        root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

        if (xmlStrcmp(root->name,(const xmlChar*) "account"))
        {
            xmlFreeDoc(doc);            
            xmlMutexUnlock(xmlmutex);
            return false;
        }

        p = root->children;

        char* nodeValue = NULL;
        nodeValue = (char*)xmlGetProp(root, (const xmlChar *)"pass");
        acc_password  = nodeValue;
        xmlFreeOTSERV(nodeValue);

        // now load in characters.
        while (p)
        {
            const char* str = (char*)p->name;

            if (strcmp(str, "characters") == 0)
            {
                tmp = p->children;
                while(tmp)
                {
                    nodeValue = (char*)xmlGetProp(tmp, (xmlChar*)"name");

                    if(nodeValue) {
                        if(strcmp((const char*)tmp->name, "character") == 0) {
                            if(nodeValue == name){
                                password = acc_password;
                                xmlFreeOTSERV(nodeValue);
                                xmlFreeDoc(doc);
                                xmlMutexUnlock(xmlmutex);
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        xmlFreeOTSERV(nodeValue);
                    }

                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
            }
            p = p->next;
        }

        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    }   
    xmlMutexUnlock(xmlmutex);
    return false;
}

#ifdef YUR_BUILTIN_AAC
bool IOAccountXML::saveAccount(const Account& account)
{
    xmlMutexLock(xmlmutex);
    xmlNodePtr root, charsNode, charNode;

    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlNewDoc((const xmlChar*)"1.0");
    doc->children = xmlNewDocNode(doc, NULL, (const xmlChar*)"account", NULL);
    root = doc->children;

    xmlSetProp(root, (const xmlChar*)"pass", (const xmlChar*)account.password.c_str());
    xmlSetProp(root, (const xmlChar*)"type", (const xmlChar*)str(account.accType).c_str());
    xmlSetProp(root, (const xmlChar*)"premDays", (const xmlChar*)str(account.premDays).c_str());

    charsNode = xmlNewNode(NULL, (const xmlChar*)"characters");
    xmlAddChild(root, charsNode);

    std::list<std::string>::const_iterator iter = account.charList.begin();
    while (iter != account.charList.end())
    {
        charNode = xmlNewNode(NULL, (const xmlChar*)"character");
        xmlSetProp(charNode, (const xmlChar*)"name", (const xmlChar*)(*iter).c_str());
        xmlAddChild(charsNode, charNode);
        ++iter;
    }

    std::ostringstream filename;
    filename << g_config.DATA_DIR << "accounts/" << account.accnumber << ".xml";
    std::string file = filename.str();

    if (xmlSaveFile(file.c_str(), doc))
    {
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        xmlMutexUnlock(xmlmutex);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        xmlMutexUnlock(xmlmutex);
        std::cout << "Failed to save " << file << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
#endif //YUR_BUILTIN_AAC
```

luascript.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "luascript.h"
#include "player.h"

extern "C"
{
#include "LUA/lua.h"
#include "LUA/lauxlib.h"
#include "LUA/lualib.h"
}



LuaScript::LuaScript()
{
  luaState = NULL;
}


LuaScript::~LuaScript()
{
  if (luaState)
      lua_close(luaState);
}


int LuaScript::OpenFile(const char *filename)
{
    luaState = lua_open();

    if (lua_dofile(luaState, filename))
        return false;

#ifdef YUR_MULTIPLIERS
    EXP_MUL = getGlobalNumber("expmul",1);
    EXP_MUL_PVP = getGlobalNumber("expmulpvp",1);
    HEALTH_TICK_MUL = getGlobalNumber("healthtickmul",1);
    MANA_TICK_MUL = getGlobalNumber("manatickmul",1);

    CAP_GAIN[VOCATION_NONE] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("capgain", VOCATION_NONE + 1, "10").c_str());
    CAP_GAIN[VOCATION_SORCERER] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("capgain", VOCATION_SORCERER + 1, "10").c_str());
    CAP_GAIN[VOCATION_DRUID] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("capgain", VOCATION_DRUID + 1, "10").c_str());
    CAP_GAIN[VOCATION_PALADIN] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("capgain", VOCATION_PALADIN + 1, "20").c_str());
    CAP_GAIN[VOCATION_KNIGHT] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("capgain", VOCATION_KNIGHT + 1, "25").c_str());

    MANA_GAIN[VOCATION_NONE] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("managain", VOCATION_NONE + 1, "5").c_str());
    MANA_GAIN[VOCATION_SORCERER] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("managain", VOCATION_SORCERER + 1, "30").c_str());
    MANA_GAIN[VOCATION_DRUID] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("managain", VOCATION_DRUID + 1, "30").c_str());
    MANA_GAIN[VOCATION_PALADIN] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("managain", VOCATION_PALADIN + 1, "15").c_str());
    MANA_GAIN[VOCATION_KNIGHT] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("managain", VOCATION_KNIGHT + 1, "5").c_str());

    HP_GAIN[VOCATION_NONE] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("hpgain", VOCATION_NONE + 1, "5").c_str());
    HP_GAIN[VOCATION_SORCERER] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("hpgain", VOCATION_SORCERER + 1, "5").c_str());
    HP_GAIN[VOCATION_DRUID] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("hpgain", VOCATION_DRUID + 1, "5").c_str());
    HP_GAIN[VOCATION_PALADIN] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("hpgain", VOCATION_PALADIN + 1, "10").c_str());
    HP_GAIN[VOCATION_KNIGHT] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("hpgain", VOCATION_KNIGHT + 1, "15").c_str());

    WEAPON_MUL[VOCATION_NONE] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("weaponmul", VOCATION_NONE+1, "1").c_str());
    WEAPON_MUL[VOCATION_SORCERER] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("weaponmul", VOCATION_SORCERER+1, "1").c_str());
    WEAPON_MUL[VOCATION_DRUID] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("weaponmul", VOCATION_DRUID+1, "1").c_str());
    WEAPON_MUL[VOCATION_PALADIN] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("weaponmul", VOCATION_PALADIN+1, "1").c_str());
    WEAPON_MUL[VOCATION_KNIGHT] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("weaponmul", VOCATION_KNIGHT+1, "1").c_str());

    DIST_MUL[VOCATION_NONE] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("distmul", VOCATION_NONE+1, "1").c_str());
    DIST_MUL[VOCATION_SORCERER] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("distmul", VOCATION_SORCERER+1, "1").c_str());
    DIST_MUL[VOCATION_DRUID] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("distmul", VOCATION_DRUID+1, "1").c_str());
    DIST_MUL[VOCATION_PALADIN] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("distmul", VOCATION_PALADIN+1, "1").c_str());
    DIST_MUL[VOCATION_KNIGHT] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("distmul", VOCATION_KNIGHT+1, "1").c_str());

    SHIELD_MUL[VOCATION_NONE] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("shieldmul", VOCATION_NONE+1, "1").c_str());
    SHIELD_MUL[VOCATION_SORCERER] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("shieldmul", VOCATION_SORCERER+1, "1").c_str());
    SHIELD_MUL[VOCATION_DRUID] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("shieldmul", VOCATION_DRUID+1, "1").c_str());
    SHIELD_MUL[VOCATION_PALADIN] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("shieldmul", VOCATION_PALADIN+1, "1").c_str());
    SHIELD_MUL[VOCATION_KNIGHT] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("shieldmul", VOCATION_KNIGHT+1, "1").c_str());

    MANA_MUL[VOCATION_NONE] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("manamul", VOCATION_NONE+1, "1").c_str());
    MANA_MUL[VOCATION_SORCERER] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("manamul", VOCATION_SORCERER+1, "1").c_str());
    MANA_MUL[VOCATION_DRUID] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("manamul", VOCATION_DRUID+1, "1").c_str());
    MANA_MUL[VOCATION_PALADIN] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("manamul", VOCATION_PALADIN+1, "1").c_str());
    MANA_MUL[VOCATION_KNIGHT] = atoi(getGlobalStringField("manamul", VOCATION_KNIGHT+1, "1").c_str());
#endif //YUR_MULTIPLIERS

#ifdef TR_ANTI_AFK
    KICK_TIME = getGlobalNumber("kicktime",15)*60000;
#endif //TR_ANTI_AFK

#ifdef YUR_LEARN_SPELLS
    LEARN_SPELLS = getGlobalString("learnspells") == "yes";
#endif //YUR_LEARN_SPELLS

#ifdef TLM_HOUSE_SYSTEM
    ACCESS_HOUSE = getGlobalNumber("accesshouse",3);
    MAX_HOUSE_TILE_ITEMS = getGlobalNumber("maxhousetileitems",10);
#endif //TLM_HOUSE_SYSTEM

#ifdef TR_SUMMONS
    SUMMONS_ALL_VOC = getGlobalString("summonsallvoc") == "yes";
    MAX_SUMMONS = (size_t)getGlobalNumber("maxsummons",2);
#endif //TR_SUMMONS

#ifdef TLM_SKULLS_PARTY
    HIT_TIME = getGlobalNumber("hittime",1)*60000;
    WHITE_TIME = getGlobalNumber("whitetime",15)*60000;
    RED_TIME = getGlobalNumber("redtime",5*60)*60000;
    FRAG_TIME = getGlobalNumber("fragtime",10*60)*60000;
    RED_UNJUST = getGlobalNumber("redunjust",3);
    BAN_UNJUST = getGlobalNumber("banunjust",6);
#endif //TLM_SKULLS_PARTY

#ifdef SD_BURST_ARROW
    BURST_DMG_LVL = atof(getGlobalStringField("burstarrowdmg", 1, "2.0").c_str());
    BURST_DMG_MLVL = atof(getGlobalStringField("burstarrowdmg", 2, "3.0").c_str());
    BURST_DMG_LO = atof(getGlobalStringField("burstarrowdmg", 3, "0.24").c_str());
    BURST_DMG_HI = atof(getGlobalStringField("burstarrowdmg", 4, "0.55").c_str());
#endif //SD_BURST_ARROW

#ifdef YUR_CONFIG_CAP
    CAP_SYSTEM = getGlobalString("capsystem") == "yes";
#endif //YUR_CONFIG_CAP

#ifdef BDB_REPLACE_SPEARS
    SPEAR_LOSE_CHANCE = getGlobalNumber("spearlosechance",50);
#endif //BDB_REPLACE_SPEARS

#ifdef YUR_PREMIUM_PROMOTION
    FREE_PREMMY = getGlobalString("freepremmy") == "yes";
    QUEUE_PREMMY = getGlobalString("queuepremmy") == "yes";
#endif //YUR_PREMIUM_PROMOTION

#ifdef YUR_CVS_MODS
    VOCATIONS[VOCATION_KNIGHT] = getGlobalStringField("vocations",VOCATION_KNIGHT);
    VOCATIONS[VOCATION_PALADIN] = getGlobalStringField("vocations",VOCATION_PALADIN);
    VOCATIONS[VOCATION_SORCERER] = getGlobalStringField("vocations",VOCATION_SORCERER);
    VOCATIONS[VOCATION_DRUID] = getGlobalStringField("vocations",VOCATION_DRUID);

    PROMOTED_VOCATIONS[VOCATION_KNIGHT] = getGlobalStringField("promoted_vocations",VOCATION_KNIGHT);
    PROMOTED_VOCATIONS[VOCATION_PALADIN] = getGlobalStringField("promoted_vocations",VOCATION_PALADIN);
    PROMOTED_VOCATIONS[VOCATION_SORCERER] = getGlobalStringField("promoted_vocations",VOCATION_SORCERER);
    PROMOTED_VOCATIONS[VOCATION_DRUID] = getGlobalStringField("promoted_vocations",VOCATION_DRUID);

    DIE_PERCENT_EXP = atoi(getGlobalStringField("diepercent",1,"7").c_str());
    DIE_PERCENT_MANA = atoi(getGlobalStringField("diepercent",2,"7").c_str());
    DIE_PERCENT_SKILL = atoi(getGlobalStringField("diepercent",3,"7").c_str());
    DIE_PERCENT_EQ = atoi(getGlobalStringField("diepercent",4,"7").c_str());
    DIE_PERCENT_BP = atoi(getGlobalStringField("diepercent",5,"100").c_str());

    ACCESS_PROTECT = getGlobalNumber("accessprotect",3);
    ACCESS_REMOTE = getGlobalNumber("accessremote",3);
    ACCESS_TALK = getGlobalNumber("accesstalk",3);
    ACCESS_ENTER = getGlobalNumber("accessenter",3);
    ACCESS_LOOK = getGlobalNumber("accesslook",3);

    EXHAUSTED = getGlobalNumber("exhausted",0);
    EXHAUSTED_ADD = getGlobalNumber("exhaustedadd",0);
    EXHAUSTED_HEAL = getGlobalNumber("exhaustedheal",0);

    PZ_LOCKED = getGlobalNumber("pzlocked",0);
    MAX_DEPOT_ITEMS = getGlobalNumber("maxdepotitem",1000);
    DATA_DIR = getGlobalString("datadir");
#endif //YUR_CVS_MODS

#ifdef JD_DEATH_LIST
    MAX_DEATH_ENTRIES = getGlobalNumber("maxdeathentries",10);
#endif //JD_DEATH_LIST

#ifdef JD_WANDS
    MANA_SNAKEBITE = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodmana", 1, "2").c_str());
    MANA_MOONLIGHT = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodmana", 2, "3").c_str());
    MANA_VOLCANIC = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodmana", 3, "5").c_str());
    MANA_QUAGMIRE = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodmana", 4, "8").c_str());
    MANA_TEMPEST = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodmana", 5, "13").c_str());

    MANA_VORTEX = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandmana", 1, "2").c_str());
    MANA_DRAGONBREATH = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandmana", 2, "3").c_str());
    MANA_PLAGUE = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandmana", 3, "5").c_str());
    MANA_COSMIC = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandmana", 4, "8").c_str());
    MANA_INFERNO = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandmana", 5, "13").c_str());

    RANGE_SNAKEBITE = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodrange", 1, "4").c_str());
    RANGE_MOONLIGHT = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodrange", 2, "3").c_str());
    RANGE_VOLCANIC = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodrange", 3, "2").c_str());
    RANGE_QUAGMIRE = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodrange", 4, "1").c_str());
    RANGE_TEMPEST = atoi(getGlobalStringField("rodrange", 5, "3").c_str());

    RANGE_VORTEX = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandrange", 1, "4").c_str());
    RANGE_DRAGONBREATH = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandrange", 2, "3").c_str());
    RANGE_PLAGUE = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandrange", 3, "2").c_str());
    RANGE_COSMIC = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandrange", 4, "1").c_str());
    RANGE_INFERNO = atoi(getGlobalStringField("wandrange", 5, "3").c_str());
#endif //JD_WANDS

#ifdef YUR_BUILTIN_AAC
    ACCMAKER = getGlobalString("accmaker") != "none";
    ACCMAKER_ROOK = getGlobalString("accmaker") == "rook";
#endif //YUR_BUILTIN_AAC

    return true;
}


std::string LuaScript::getGlobalString(std::string var, const std::string &defString)
{
    lua_getglobal(luaState, var.c_str());

  if(!lua_isstring(luaState, -1))
      return defString;

    int len = (int)lua_strlen(luaState, -1);
    std::string ret(lua_tostring(luaState, -1), len);
    lua_pop(luaState,1);

    return ret;
}

int LuaScript::getGlobalNumber(std::string var, const int defNum)
{
    lua_getglobal(luaState, var.c_str());

  if(!lua_isnumber(luaState, -1))
      return defNum;

    int val = (int)lua_tonumber(luaState, -1);
    lua_pop(luaState,1);

    return val;
}


int LuaScript::setGlobalString(std::string var, std::string val)
{
    return false;
}

int LuaScript::setGlobalNumber(std::string var, int val){
    lua_pushnumber(luaState, val);
    lua_setglobal(luaState, var.c_str());
    return true;
}

std::string LuaScript::getGlobalStringField (std::string var, const int key, const std::string &defString) {
      lua_getglobal(luaState, var.c_str());

      lua_pushnumber(luaState, key);
      lua_gettable(luaState, -2);  /* get table[key] */
      if(!lua_isstring(luaState, -1))
      return defString;
      std::string result = lua_tostring(luaState, -1);
      lua_pop(luaState, 2);  /* remove number and key*/
      return result;
}

int LuaScript::getField (const char *key) {
      int result;
      lua_pushstring(luaState, key);
      lua_gettable(luaState, -2);  /* get table[key] */
      result = (int)lua_tonumber(luaState, -1);
      lua_pop(luaState, 1);  /* remove number and key*/
      return result;
}

void LuaScript::setField (const char *index, int val) {
      lua_pushstring(luaState, index);
      lua_pushnumber(luaState, (double)val);
      lua_settable(luaState, -3);
    }


int LuaScript::getField (lua_State *L , const char *key) {
      int result;
      lua_pushstring(L, key);
      lua_gettable(L, -2);  /* get table[key] */
      result = (int)lua_tonumber(L, -1);
      lua_pop(L, 1);  /* remove number and key*/
      return result;
}

void LuaScript::setField (lua_State *L, const char *index, int val) {
      lua_pushstring(L, index);
      lua_pushnumber(L, (double)val);
      lua_settable(L, -3);
    }
```

luascript.h

```
#ifndef __LUASCRIPT_H__
#define __LUASCRIPT_H__

#include <string>
extern "C"
{
#include "LUA/lua.h"
#include "LUA/lauxlib.h"
#include "LUA/lualib.h"
```

_

```
soemone know how to fix it?
```

acctions.h

```
#ifndef __actions_h_
#define __actions_h_


#include "position.h"

#include "libxml/xmlmemory.h"
#include "libxml/parser.h"

#include <map>

#include "luascript.h"

extern "C"
{
#include "LUA/lua.h"
#include "LUA/lauxlib.h"
#include "LUA/lualib.h"
#include "LUA/luaconf.h"
}
```

actions.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "definitions.h"
#include "const76.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "monster.h"
#include "npc.h"
#include "game.h"
#include "item.h"

#include "libxml/xmlmemory.h"
#include "libxml/parser.h"

#include "actions.h"
```

otserv.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "definitions.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

#include "otsystem.h"
#include "networkmessage.h"
#include "protocol76.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "game.h"

#include "ioaccount.h"
#include "ioplayer.h"

#include "status.h"
#include "spells.h"
#include "monsters.h"
#include "actions.h"
#include "commands.h"

#include "luascript.h"
#include "account.h"

#include "tools.h"
#include "md5.h"

#include "summons.h"
#include "pvparena.h"
#include "readables.h"
#include "aac.h"
```

npc.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "definitions.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

#include "libxml/xmlmemory.h"
#include "libxml/parser.h"

#include "npc.h"
#include "luascript.h"
#include "player.h"
```

npc.h

```
#ifndef __npc_h_
#define __npc_h_


#include "creature.h"
#include "game.h"
#include "luascript.h"
#include "templates.h"

extern "C"
{
#include "LUA/lua.h"
#include "LUA/lauxlib.h"
#include "LUA/lualib.h"
}
```

Someone know how to fix it?
 I use visual studio 2013

Comment: Include required library file (should be libXML or similar)

Comment: The compilation step is fine, your linker doesn't find the object files for (among others) the lua library. Add them to your project ( on the command line use `-L` and `-l` switches ).

Comment: [The top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) from that search box in your upper-right corner by by simply typing `[cpp] unresolved external` is pretty informative, and considerably more efficient than posting the wall of code in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the project in the solution explorer. 
Select "Linker" 
In the "Input section" state the name of the Lua (and xml and all other libraries) library you are trying to use. 
In the "General" section, specify where this library is in the "Additional Library Directories".


In general the "unresolved external" message has several previous answers: e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297952/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol). The specifics of the various IDEs vary slightly.

Comment: here ? http://s17.postimg.org/h5cnz2x67/Screen_Shot_02_20_15_at_01_43_PM.png

Comment: That screenshot is blocked from where I am - what do you mean?

Comment: click on files properties general Additional include directories?